# Showing a codimension one Chow group is trivial.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm having problems with the following question. Let $k$ be a field, and $R=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$. How do I show that the codimension one Chow group $\operatorname{Div}(R)/K(R)^{\times}=0$ and that this implies that $\phi:\operatorname{Pic}(R)\mapsto \operatorname{Div}(R)/K(R)^{\times}$ is not a monomorphism. I don't even know how to start so I appreciate your help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a [no-clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has an inclusion $R\to k[t]$, given by $y\mapsto t^3,x\mapsto t^2$. This is clearly finite and thus one has a surjective map $CH_0(\operatorname{Spec}k[t])\to CH_0(\operatorname{Spec}R)$. $CH_0(\operatorname{Spec} k[t])=0$ since $k[t]$ is a pid.